# Why does "ndarray.all() is False" always returns False in python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Was wondering about the logic in python. When using any() or all() on a numpy array and using is False/True I always get False, but when using "==" I get the answer I expect.
So

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([True,False,True])
a.any() is False 
>False
a.any() is True
>False
```

but this work as expected

```
a.any() == True
>True
a.any() == False
>False
```

Comment: Because the return value of `any` will **never** be identitcal to `True` or `False`, which are language guaranteed singltons of type `bool`, whereas `any` always returns an object of type `numpy.bool_` not `bool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is` operator is comparing if the objects are the same (have the same `id`). The `==` operator compares two *values*. You can see that the value is the same (`True`), but the `id` is different. See:

```py
In [4]: id(True)
Out[4]: 140734689232720

In [5]: id(a.any())
Out[5]: 140734684830488
```

So what you are seeing is two different objects that have similar human readable, printed value "True". As AKX noted, these two objects are of different type: `True` is `bool` but `a.any()` is `numpy.bool_`.

#### Note on comparing values with booleans

As a side note, you typically would not want to compare to boolean with `is`, so no

```py
if a.any() is False:
   # do something
```

this is a perfect example why not. In general you are interested if the values are [*truthy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/3015186), not `True`. Also, there is no point in comparing to boolean even with `==` operator:

```py
if a.any() == False:
   # do something
```

instead, a pythonic way would be to just write

```py
if not a.any():
   # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy operations return Numpy types.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([True,False,True])
>>> a.any()
True
>>> type(a.any())
<class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

Never use `is` for comparisons (unless you know you really need it, which is very rarely).

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to compare a boolean to a boolean, just use the boolean directly or its negation.

Comment: Yup. Or if you need a Python `bool` for whatever reason, cast it with e.g. `bool(a.any())`.